# how to convert jason file data into csv file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have `.json` file which have this type of data ,the name of universities of the world

```
[
  {
    "web_pages": [
      "https://www.cstj.qc.ca",
      "https://ccmt.cstj.qc.ca",
      "https://ccml.cstj.qc.ca"
    ],
    "name": "CÃ©gep de Saint-JÃ©rÃ´me",
    "alpha_two_code": "CA",
    "state-province": null,
    "domains": [
      "cstj.qc.ca"
    ],
    "country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "web_pages": [
      "http://www.lindenwood.edu/"
    ],
    "name": "Lindenwood University",
    "alpha_two_code": "US",
    "state-province": null,
    "domains": [
      "lindenwood.edu"
    ],
    "country": "United States"
  },
  {
    "web_pages": [
.......
.....
....
...
Continue......
```

I want to convert this `.json` file into `CSV` using Python, What will be its solution to make the CSV file?

Comment: First of all, I'd advise you to try parsing the JSON with a different encoding - your current one seems to be generating all sorts of weird characters.

Comment: Do you have Pandas, or you want to do this with only core Python?

Comment: @SupratimHaldar I am using simple IDL python 3.6 ,Install it and then I am using it.

Comment: Okay. I am adding this as a comment rather than an answer because this solution involves Pandas.

``import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('infile.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)

df = json_normalize(d)
df.to_csv('outfile.csv', index=False)``

Comment: @SupratimHaldar I have Install the pandas ,Can you Give me as a Answer

Comment: Added the answer below. Hope it helps.

Comment: @LucaBezerra Thanks for heighlight the point of encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses Pandas.

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('infile.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)

df = json_normalize(d)
df.to_csv('outfile.csv', index=False)
```

Also, as @LucaBezerra has mentioned in the comments, the current text has some encoding problem which you might want to fix (look at the first "name").